# Adding description to product form csv file

Tags: php, csv, magento

I wrote a code to add product description from sku. Now script works fine but all formatting seems to be lost as in csv and description added to product is partial (seems it removes string after any special character).

**My code:**

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
if (($handle = fopen("Witedescriptions.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $desc =$data[1];
        $sku = $data[2];
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
        $product->setDescription($desc);
        $product->save();
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Csv file struture

```
Sno. , Description , Sku
```

on sample data for description

```
Test this is dummy data abd’s base is of a slim yellow gold halo that easily fits on a finger. 

list here 
•   list 1
•   list 2
```

When I ran script, product has below data only:

```
Test this is dummy data abd
```

**seem it have to escape some char i tried your code with my descrition set as "Gold’s price in USA" but in admin product i just got "Gold"**

Comment: I've tested your code and there's no problem when parsing the CSV file and get the values. The problem should be here: `$product->setDescription($desc);` , so have a look to that function. I guess you need to remove/replace problematic characters from the description before storing it into the database.

Comment: it just 's thing could not find why even adding addslahes is not working

Answer (score 0):

Also to escape quotation marks use addslashes:

```
$desc = addslashes($data[1]);
```

but that does mean they need to be removed on output.

Answer (score 0):

Use these functions to escape **'** in you string.

```
$data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
```

or

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
```

or

```
public function filter($data)
    {
        $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
        // print_r($data);
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            // print_r($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            // print_r($data);
            $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
            // print_r($data);
        }
        return $data;       
    }
```